# opengGL drawing a line

Tags: c++, opengl

So far this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void display(void);
void timer(int);
static float x=0.0f,y=0.0f;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowPosition(200,200);
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
glutCreateWindow("draw a line");
glutKeyboardFunc(&keyboard);
glutDisplayFunc(&display);

glutTimerFunc(10,timer,0);

glutMainLoop();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
switch (key)
 {
 case '\x1B':
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  break;
}
}

void timer(int value){
x+=0.001;
y+=0.0005;
glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(10,timer,0);
 }

void display()
 {

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity ();
 glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex2f(x,y);
glEnd();


glFlush();
}
```

What this does is that it lights up a pixel every 10 msecs from the point (0,0) to (1,0.5). What I want is that when a pixel lights up it stays in that state, so eventually you will see a line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with `glut` but I am guessing `display` is the function that is called on each redraw. This function starts with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`. This function clears your color buffer on each redraw.

You might find that removing `glClear` does not entirely fix your problem. This could well be because your graphics context may be double buffered and to make things more efficient, the front buffer is not copied to the back buffer on each animation run.

You best bet to get the desired effect will probably be to draw a line that grows on each animation run.

Comment: I removed glClear and now the pixels are still lighten up. Thanks

Comment: If you are using double buffering, you need to call `glutSwapBuffers()` at the end of the display function instead of `glFlush()`.

Answer (score 1):

why do things the hard way? although the older OGL API is deprecated, you can use GL_LINES to do this:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(x_start,y_start);
glVertex2f(x_end,y_end);
glEnd();
```

This will draw the line fully in one go, which is easier and a bit more efficient (it also allows you to benefit from the line anti-aliasing hint).

Comment: Its not only for straight lines, I also want to make parabolae or hyperbolae

Comment: @Badshah: you'll want a linelist in that case, with a point at every compute graph point, and you'd really want the AA as well, so the curves don't look super jagged.

Answer (score 0):

The display function is being called every time you call `glutPostRedisplay()`. And every time the display function is called, you clear the screen.

You need to write a function that will iterate through all of the points you want to display. Each iteration will call something like a `drawPoint()` function.

Perhaps something like this:

```
void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
  {
      drawPoint(points(i));
  }
  glFlush();
}
```

Alternatively, you could skip writing a new function and do this:

```
 glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
 {
     glVertex2f(points(i).getX(), points(i).getY());
 }
 glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using, GL_LINES. A way to do it is to have an array of points you want to draw EG: p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5] ... then draw it using some for loop

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for(...) {
  glVertex2f(p[i  ]->x,p[i  ]->y);
  glVertex2f(p[i+1]->x,p[i+1]->y);
}
glEnd();
```

So using this method you can replace p[] with a function allowing you to make pretty shapes

```
glVertex2f(functionx(i  ),functiony(i  ));
glVertex2f(functionx(i+1),functiony(i+1));
```

note: lines work weirdly they dont link up you need to have a start point to end point kind of thing hence the i+1

I guess your trying to draw stuff like cardioid's using polar coordinates?